# Liquibase: How to execute just changeset that you want?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, liquibase

If in liquibase file you have a couple of changesets and you just want to execute the one you want, how to mention just that one by ID? And is that even possible in practice?
For the example I just want to execute the first changeset:

```
src/main/resources/liquibase/test.sql::DEV-9563::user.user
src/main/resources/liquibase/test.sql::DEV-9569::user1.user1
src/main/resources/liquibase/test.sql::DEV-9569_1::user1.user1
```

I'm using terminal in Intellij-idea.
The command for executing query is **mvn liquibase:update**

Answer (score 0):

I comment the change sets in my main change log master file until I am ready to deploy the changes to a particular environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.
You can use context or labels to achieve your goal.
Since I use it from command line , this how I do it:

let's say this your sample changeset file:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset A1:1111-1 context:dev,prod,release labels:create
create table company_test (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address1 varchar(50),
    address2 varchar(50),
    city varchar(30)
)
-- rollback drop table company_test

-- changeset A1:1111-2 context:dev,prod,release labels:alter
alter table company_test add column country varchar(2)
-- rollback alter table company_test drop column country
```

so if I only want to run first changeset, I will add a context for e.g testX or a label and update it.

the CLI command

```
liquibase --defaultsFile=env/local/liquibase.properties  --changeLogFile=changelogs/changelog.1234.sql  --logLevel=severe --defaultSchemaName=test  --contexts=testX  update
```

So you can modify your changeset with context and from maven you will have to add it in the properties file that maven takes.